# python-block try/except - display a line of text

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, exception, try-catch

My code:

```
  fname = "text.txt"
text_file = open(fname, "r")
lines = text_file.readlines()
while True:
    linenumber = int(input("Please enter a line number or press 0 to quit:  "))
    if linenumber == 0:
        print("Thanks for using the program")
        break
text_file.close()
```

How can I add an exception(try/except) handling, so that after entering, for example, the number of line 30 which does not exist, an exception appears, eg "This line does not exist", I have a big problem with it, could someone help?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need `try / except` for that; an `if` statement will do:

```py
...
while True:
    linenumber = int(input("Please enter a line number or press 0 to quit:  "))
    if linenumber == 0:
        print("Thanks for using the program")
        break
    elif linenumber < 0 or linenumber > len(lines):
        print("this line doesn't exist!)
...
```

(I guess you're making the program so that user enters 1-based indexing, so the `elif` condition has `>` instead of `>=`.)

But if you do need `try / except`, here is one way of [EAFP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360858/what-is-the-eafp-principle-in-python):

```py
...
while True:
    linenumber = int(input("Please enter a line number or press 0 to quit:  "))
    if linenumber == 0:
        print("Thanks for using the program")
        break

    try:
        lines[linenumber-1]
    except IndexError:
        print("This line does not exist")
    else:
        print("this line exists, yes")
        # do what you'd do when it exists

...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
try:
    print(lines[linenumber])
except IndexError:
    print("Line not found")
```

But you could just check if it's valid as well:

```
if len(lines) < linenumber:
    print("line not found")
```

(Noticed as in the other response that you are using 1-indexed rather than 0-indexed)
Personally I don't think entering "0" is a good exit condition.